# How to exclude a folder from a nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I'm using Octopack / Nuspec file to build my nuget package.

I would like to exclude certain folders which exist in the project. e.g. the "obj" file. I've been trying to get the exclude tag to work, but haven't had any luck. The nuget file builds, but the folder is still there.

Sadly, all the examples on the net specific file types and not folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Foo</id>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <authors>NA</authors>
    <owners>NA</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://Foo</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://Foo</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Foo</description>
    <releaseNotes>NA</releaseNotes>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="obj\**\*.*" exclude="*.*" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Can you describe for us which pieces you want to *include* in the package?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I needed to create a WebApplication, but deploy it as a standard ASP.NET website using "CodeFile" attributes.

This was basically to update a page in the standard ADFS login site.

```
<files>
  <file src="**" exclude="**\*.dll;**\*.designer.cs;**\*.csproj;**\*.pdb;**\*.user;**\*.vspscc;bin\*.cs;bin\*.aspx;bin\*.config;bin\*.asax;bin\*.pubxml" />
</files>
```

Comment: Are you required to use NuGet for this?  I wonder if a [Web Deploy package](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/building-a-web-deploy-package-from-visual-studio-2010) might be a little better fit for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yeah. We needed to use octopus deploy so nuget was a requirement.

Comment: I was tried to use this solution. but unfortunately, nothing has happened?

Answer (score 11):

To directly answer the posters question, if you want to exclude only the **obj** folder from a Nuget package use the following in your nuspec xml

```
<files>
    <file src="*\**" target="\" exclude="obj\**\*.*"/>
</files>
```

Comment: This had a lot of side efftects.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the project you are building, you shouldn't need to exclude anything.

If you are building a Windows Service/Console application, OctoPack should only package your `bin\release` directory.

If you are building a web application, you should use a 'publish' command to have MSBuild sent the binaries and content files to a temporary folder, and OctoPack will package that. This way your `obj` folders and C# files won't be packaged.

For information on how to do this, please see the section on Web Application Publishing at:

http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation/packaging/octopack

Comment: can you update this answer?  I don't see a "Web Application Publishing" section on the linked page.  My specific issue is that the bin\Roslyn folder is being included in the nupkg.  I tried using a publishing profile and running msbuild against the csproj instead, but that did not work:
&$msbuildExe ..\trunk\WebUI\WebUI.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=local /p:RunOctoPack=true

Comment: It's include files like EntityFramework.dll, which are dependencies on separate NuGet packages, NOT files that should be inlcuded in my nupkg file.  How does one exclude them?

Comment: The question wasn't for advise. It was explicitly for excluding a folder from a nuget package.