# AzureDevops Nuget Pack

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, nuget

I have a .net class library project (4.7.2) which will be built on an AzureDevops instance. In the build pipeline one step is to create a nuget package based on the corresponding *.csproj file. Within the class library project there are folders. Now when the nuget package is created the nuget package also contains the folders of the project and not only the created *.dll file. How can I avoid having the folders of the project in the created Nuget package?

Comment: Use a `.nuspec` file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452608/how-to-exclude-a-folder-from-a-nuget-package

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly control which files are included in a package, you can specify files tag in .nuspec fule.

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\*.dll" target="lib" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\*.pdb" target="lib" />
    <file src="tools\**\*.*" exclude="**\*.log" />
</files>
```

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-assembly-files) for more information

Comment: @Franz Gsell Did you tried above solution? How did it go?